# Git commit with -s flag

Tags: git, commit

If I write at the terminal `git commit -s` so it's want that i will insert a message.
But after I type a message, how can I continue with the terminal and to insert this message?

Comment: What platform are you on? Are you familiar with vim? What does `-s` have to do with this?

Comment: You need to include *much more details* in the question. At current it is hardly better than "My car does not start when I turn the key. What should I do?".

Answer (score 0):

After you type the message, you can simply save and close the editor.

On windows powershell:

1. `git commit -s`

[image: commit -s]

2. Open editor and type commit message

[image: message]

3. Save and close editor

[image: finish]

Commit is done, all left is to push.